# Enable button when conditions are true in VueJS 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am currently working on a form and are having some problems to enable a button when conditions are filled.

Currently i created a form that contains inputs to fill a name, a phonenumber, some options and a message. When the conditions are filled i want to enable the button i already disabled.

Does anyone have some tips on who i can enable the button again to submit the form?

```
<template>

    <div class="contact">
  <h1>Vi uppskattar alla frågor som du har angående denna applikation!</h1>
  <h2> Vänligen skriv ett meddelande här nedan så ska vi göra allt vi kan för att svara så snart som möjligt!</h2>
</div>

  <form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
    <div class="form-control" :class="{invalid: fullNameValidation === 'invalid'}">
      <label for="name">Namn</label>
      <input id="name" name="name" type="text" v-model="fullName" @blur="validateInput">
      <p v-if="fullNameValidation === 'invalid'">Vänligen fyll i ett namn</p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control" :class="{invalid: phoneValidation === 'invalid'}">
      <label for="phone">Telefonnummer</label>
      <input id="phone" name="phone" type="number" v-model="phoneNr" @blur="validatePhone" pattern="[0-9]*">
      <p v-if="phoneValidation === 'invalid'">Vänligen fyll i ett giltigt telefonnummer</p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="referrer">Hur fick du kännedom av denna applikation?</label>
      <select id="referrer" name="referrer" v-model="referrer">
        <option value="" disabled hidden>Välj ett alternativ</option>
        <option value="internet">Internet</option>
        <option value="friends">Vänner</option>
        <option value="newspaper">Nyhetstidningar</option>
        <option value="other">Annat</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control" :class="{invalid: messageValidation === 'invalid'}">
      <label for="message">Meddelande</label>
      <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" v-model="message" @blur="validateMessage"></textarea>
       <p v-if="messageValidation === 'invalid'">Vänligen fyll i ditt meddelande</p>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button v-on:click="$router.push('thankyou')" :disabled="!isComplete" id="myBtn">Skicka meddelande</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            fullName: '',
            fullNameValidation: 'pending',
            phoneNr: 'null',
            phoneValidation: 'pending',
            referrer: '',
            messageValidation: 'pending'
        }
    },

    methods: {
        submitForm() {
            this.fullName = '';
        },
        validateInput() {
            if (this.fullName === '') {
                this.fullNameValidation = 'valid'
            } else {
                this.fullNameValidation = 'invalid'
            }
        },
        validatePhone() {
            if (this.phoneNr > 10) {
                this.phoneValidation = 'valid'
            } else {
                this.phoneValidation = 'invalid'
            }
        },
         validateMessage() {
            if (this.messageValidation > 1) {
                this.messageValidation = 'valid'
            } else {
                this.messageValidation = 'invalid'
            }
        },

        computed: {
       isComplete() {
          return Object.values(this.fields).every(({valid}) => valid)
      }
  }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consolidate your form fields into a single model, along with the errors object.

Then use `Object.keys` to grab known field keys to do validation on.

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        errors: {},
        values: {
          fullName: '',
          phoneNr: '',
          referrer: '',
        }
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    validate(field) {

      let fields = []
      // single field
      if (field) {
        delete this.form.errors[field]
        fields.push(field)
      } else {
        this.form.errors = {}
        // all fields
        fields = Object.keys(this.form.values)
      }


      if (fields.includes('fullName')) {
        if (this.form.values.fullName === '') {
          this.form.errors.fullName = 'Enter your full name'
        } else if (this.fullName !== some other validation) {
          ...
        }
      }

      if (fields.includes('phoneNr')) {
        if (this.form.values.phoneNr === '') {
          this.form.errors.phoneNr = 'Enter your phone number'
        }
      }

      if (fields.includes('referrer')) {
        if (this.form.values.referrer === '') {
          this.form.errors.referrer = 'Enter referrer'
        }
      }

      // if errors is empty return true
      return !Object.keys(this.form.errors).length
    },
    submit() {
      // validate all
      if (this.validate()) {
        // do some thing, form is valid, if native form handler, return true/false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-control" :class="{invalid: form.errors.fullName}">
  <label for="name">Namn</label>
  <input id="name" type="text" v-model="fullName" @blur="validate('fullName')">
  <p v-if="form.errors.fullName">{{ form.errors.fullName }}</p>
</div>
```

If you don't specifically need the `@blur` validation, it simplifies things quite abit and its pretty standard to do validation on submit rather then on blur of individual fields.

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        errors: {},
        values: {
          fullName: '',
          phoneNr: '',
          referrer: '',
        }
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    validate() {

      this.form.errors = {}

      if (this.form.values.fullName === '') {
        this.form.errors.fullName = 'Enter your full name'
      } else if (this.form.values.fullName !== some other validation) {
        ...
      }

      if (this.form.values.phoneNr === '') {
        this.form.errors.phoneNr = 'Enter your phone number'
      }


      if (this.form.values.referrer === '') {
        this.form.errors.referrer = 'Enter referrer'
      }


      // if errors is empty return true
      return !Object.keys(this.form.errors).length
    },
    submit() {
      if (this.validate()) {
        // do something, form is valid, if native form handler, return true/false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
<div class="form-control" :class="{invalid: form.errors.fullName}">
  <label for="name">Namn</label>
  <input id="name" type="text" v-model="fullName">
  <p v-if="form.errors.fullName">{{ form.errors.fullName }}</p>
</div>
```